# Why is my if statement within an it block getting ignored?

Tags: android, testing, webdriver, mocha.js

I am using JavaScript, Appium, Mocha, and Webdriver.io to do end to end testing on an android application. I am trying to create an if statement for "if this button is on the screen then press it, if not press this button". For some reason it completely ignores the if statement and just reads it like it is a normal line of code.

Here are my page objects:

```
class createACompanyFirstTimeBtn {
    // For the first time
    get createNewCompanyBtn(){
        return $('id=com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_create');
    }
    // All times after
    get createAnotherNewCompanyBtn(){
        return $('id=com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right');
    }

    // CHECKER
    get checker_aCompanyExists(){
        return $('id=com.truckpay.truckpay:id/tv_lineOne');
    }

    get checker_aCompanyDoesNotExist(){
        return $('id=com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_create');
    } 
}

module.exports = new createACompanyFirstTimeBtn();
```

Here is the code I am trying to run (it is within a describe block):
In plain english, it is saying, if this item exists click create another company. If that button does not exist click createANewCompanyBtn. However when I run it it keeps trying to hit the "createAnotherNewCompanyBtn" even when the checker does not appear on the screen. Maybe the if statement is just checking if it is something existing in my files? If so how would I make it check if it is existing on the screen?

```
  it('it checks if a company has already been created or not', async () => {
  if (createACompanyFirstTimeBtn.checker_aCompanyExists) {
      console.log('IT CREATED A COMPANY AGAIN');
      await createACompanyFirstTimeBtn.createAnotherNewCompanyBtn.click();
      await driver.pause(3000);
  
  } else {
      console.log('IT CREATED A COMPANY FOR THE FIRST TIME');
      await createACompanyFirstTimeBtn.createNewCompanyBtn.click();
      await driver.pause(3000);
  }
});
```

Here is the error log:

```
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:14.625Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElements("id", "com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right")
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:14.626Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session/469623be-a1a9-4922-8c0e-95c099dace73/elements
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:14.626Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'id', value: 'com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right' }
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:14.649Z INFO webdriver: RESULT []
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.126Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElements("id", "com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right")
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.127Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session/469623be-a1a9-4922-8c0e-95c099dace73/elements
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.127Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'id', value: 'com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right' }
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.145Z INFO webdriver: RESULT []
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.626Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElements("id", "com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right")
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.627Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session/469623be-a1a9-4922-8c0e-95c099dace73/elements
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.627Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'id', value: 'com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right' }
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:15.647Z INFO webdriver: RESULT []
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:16.127Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElements("id", "com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right")
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:16.128Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session/469623be-a1a9-4922-8c0e-95c099dace73/elements
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:16.129Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'id', value: 'com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right' }
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:16.148Z INFO webdriver: RESULT []
[0-0] Error in "truckPay create a company for the first time.it checks if a company has already been created or not"
Error: Can't call click on element with selector "id=com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right" because element wasn't found
    at async Context.<anonymous> (/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/appium-docs-test-hello-world/tests/specs/createACompanyForFirstTime.js:72:7)
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:16.633Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()
[0-0] 2022-09-02T20:45:16.633Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://localhost:4723/session/469623be-a1a9-4922-8c0e-95c099dace73
[0-0] FAILED in android - /tests/specs/createACompanyForFirstTime.js
2022-09-02T20:45:17.006Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2022-09-02T20:45:17.007Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

 "spec" Reporter:
------------------------------------------------------------------
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] Running: emulator-5554 on android 10 executing /Users/christianfortin/Desktop/TRUCKPAY/android/android-official-new/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] Session ID: 469623be-a1a9-4922-8c0e-95c099dace73
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] » /tests/specs/createACompanyForFirstTime.js
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] truckPay create a company for the first time
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    ✓ it puts in the wrong credentials
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    ✓ it hits the login button and logs in
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    ✖ it checks if a company has already been created or not
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it chooses what type of company it is
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it enters a new company with no details - Error
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it clicks on the add photo button and cancels
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it enters a new company name details
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it enters a new company phone number and address
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it scrolls down to the bottom section
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it enters minority - SSN or EIN - USDOT
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it goes through general liability doc option
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]    - it enters a new company with new details
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] 2 passing (20.9s)
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] 1 failing
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] 9 skipped
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] 1) truckPay create a company for the first time it checks if a company has already been created or not
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] Can't call click on element with selector "id=com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right" because element wasn't found
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0] Error: Can't call click on element with selector "id=com.truckpay.truckpay:id/btn_right" because element wasn't found
[emulator-5554 android 10 #0-0]     at async Context.<anonymous> (/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/XXXXXX/appium-docs-test-hello-world/tests/specs/createACompanyForFirstTime.js:72:7)


Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:30 

2022-09-02T20:45:17.007Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2022-09-02T20:45:17.259Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2022-09-02T20:45:17.261Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
XXXXXXX:appium-docs-test-hello-world/ (main✗) $
```

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are testing the result of an API (`createACompanyFirstTimeBtn.checker_aCompanyExists`) that returns a Promise. And since Promises are considered as truthy, it always runs the `then` of the condition rather than the `else`.

You simply need to add an await in your condition to resolve your issue:

```js
if (await createACompanyFirstTimeBtn.checker_aCompanyExists) {
  /* ... */
} else {
  /* ... */
}
```